Prove a random variable to be a martingale
I met this question in $\,$ 'Introduction to Stochastic Integration $\,$ (by Hui-Hsiung Kuo)' on Page 59:
15. Show that $\enspace X_t = \exp[B(t)]−1−\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\exp[B(s)]ds\enspace$ is a martingale.
I tried to solve it but failed, here is how far I could get:
$\forall r\in\mathbb R\enspace$ s.t. $\enspace0\leq r\leq t$, $\enspace$let $\enspace\mathscr F^B_r=\sigma\left(\left\{B(s)\,|\,0\leq s\leq r\right\}\right)\enspace$ be the filtration generated by Brownian motion, we have
\begin{align*}
  E\left[X_t\,|\,\mathscr F^B_r\right] &= E\left[\exp[B(t)]−1−\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\exp[B(s)]ds\,|\,\mathscr F^B_r\right] \\
    &= E\left[\exp[B(t)-B(r)]\exp[B(r)]−1−\frac{1}{2}\int_r^t\exp[B(s)]ds−\frac{1}{2}\int_0^r\exp[B(s)]ds\,|\,\mathscr F^B_r\right] \\
    &= E\bigg[\exp[B(t)-B(r)]\bigg]\exp[B(r)]-1-\frac{1}{2}E\left[\int_r^t\exp[B(s)]ds\right]−\frac{1}{2}\int_0^r\exp[B(s)]ds
\end{align*}
and we want to prove
$$E\left[X_t\,|\,\mathscr F^B_r\right]=X_r$$
notice that
$$X_r=\exp[B(r)]−1−\frac{1}{2}\int_0^r\exp[B(s)]ds$$
so the problem is equivalent to proving:
\begin{align*}
  0 &= E\left[X_t\,|\,\mathscr F^B_r\right]-X_r \\
    &= E\bigg[\exp[B(t)-B(r)]\bigg]\exp[B(r)]-\exp[B(r)]-\frac{1}{2}E\left[\int_r^t\exp[B(s)]ds\right]
\end{align*}
i.e.
$$E\bigg[\exp[B(t)-B(r)]\bigg]\exp[B(r)]-\exp[B(r)]=\frac{1}{2}E\left[\int_r^t\exp[B(s)]ds\right]$$
I was stuck here.
Any advice will be appreciated!

Let $X_t$ be the stochastic process defined by
$$X_t=e^{B_t}-1-\frac12\int_0^t e^{B_s}\,ds$$
where $B_t$ is a Wiener process.  For $r<t$, we have
$$X_r=e^{B_r}-1-\frac12\int_0^r e^{B_s}\,ds$$
By definition, a martingale is a sequence of random variables (i.e., a stochastic process) for which, at a particular time, the conditional expectation of the next value in the sequence is equal to the present value.  Hence, we need to show that $\mathbb{E}_r\{X_t\}=X_r$ for all $r<t$.
Proceeding, we make use of the fact that the expected value at time $r$ of the stochastic process $e^{B_t}$, $t>r$, is equal to $e^{B_r}e^{(t-r)/2}$.  Then, we see that
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_r\{X_t\}&=\mathbb{E}_r\left[e^{B_t}-1-\frac12 \int_0^t e^{B_s}\,ds\right]\\\\
&= \mathbb{E}_r\left[e^{B_t}\right]-1-\frac12 \mathbb{E}_r\left[\int_0^t e^{B_s}\,ds\right]\\\\
&=e^{B_r}e^{(t-r)/2}-1-\frac12\int_0^r e^{B_s}\,ds-\frac12 \mathbb{E}_r\left[\int_r^t e^{B_s}\,ds\right]\\\\
&=X_r+\left(e^{B_r}e^{(t-r)/2}-e^{B_r}-\frac12 \mathbb{E}_r\left[\int_r^t e^{B_s}\,ds\right]\right)\\\\
&=X_r+\left(e^{B_r}e^{(t-r)/2}-e^{B_r}-\frac12 \int_r^t \mathbb{E}_r\left[e^{B_s}\right]\,ds\right)\\\\
&=X_r+\left(e^{B_r}e^{(t-r)/2}-e^{B_r}-\frac12 \int_r^t e^{B_r}e^{(s-r/2)}\,ds\right)\\\\
&=X_r+\left(e^{B_r}e^{(t-r)/2}-e^{B_r}-\frac12e^{B_r}\left(2e^{(t-r)/2}-2\right)\right)\\\\
&=X_r
\end{align}$$
Hence $X_t$ is a martingale.  And we are done!

Detailed answer, I appreciate it! Line 5 is the same as Line 3 and I guess you forgot to delete it. Anyway, the whole deduction is correct.

My Pleasure.  I've deleted the inadvertently repeated line.

By Ito
$$
dX_t=e^{B_t}\,dB_t+\tfrac12e^{B_t}\,dt-\tfrac12e^{B_t}\,dt=e^{B_t}\,dB_t\,.
$$
Since
$$
\mathbb E\left[\textstyle\int_0^te^{2B_s}\,ds\right]=
\textstyle\int_0^t\mathbb E[e^{2B_s}]\,ds=\int_0^te^{2s}\,ds=\displaystyle\frac{e^{2t}-1}2
$$
we see that $X$ is a stochastic integral of BM whose intgrand is in $L^2\,.$
Therefore, $X$ is a martingale.

A concise proof, thanks a lot!

@kurtg.  Hi Kurt.  I hope that you're doing well.  In my post, I assumed that $B_t$ is a Wiener process.  If so, then I agree that $dX_t=e^{B_t}dB_t$ from application of Ito's lemma.  But what is the relevance of the expectation of $\int_0^t e^{2B_s},ds$?  Are you calculating the variance of $X_t$ to ensure that the variance is in $L^2$?  If so, how does this relate to the martingale definition?

@MarkViola A stochastic integral per se is only a local martingale. To show it is a true martingale we usually show that the integrand is in $L^2,.$ Theorem 4.6.1 on p. 53 in Khuo's book that OP is using. You can find that in all other equivalent books.

Although Ito formula solves the problem immediately, I still think it is a bit overkill. You can continue your approach as follows (you forgot to condition on $F_r$ in the last equation). By independence,
\begin{align*}
E \left[ \int_r^t \exp(B_s)ds | \mathcal F_r \right] &= E \left[ \int_r^t \exp(B_s-B_r)ds \right]\exp(B_r) \\ 
&=  \int_0^{t-r} E \left[\exp(B_s) \right]ds \times\exp(B_r)  \\
&= \exp(B_r)\int_0^{t-r} e^{s/2}ds \\
&= 2\exp(B_r)(e^{(t-r)/2} -1).
\end{align*}
And also note that
$$ E[\exp(B_t-B_r)] = E[\exp(B_{t-r})] = e^{(t-r)/2}$$

I got it, much thanks! I was stuck here because I didn't realize that I could use translation invariance property of BM (change of integration variable) and Fubini's theorem (switching order of integrations). Your proof is better since Ito formula isn't in the content of the chapter yielding this question.
